# Espresso UI error on ViewModelProviders.of

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-espresso, dagger-2

I'm trying to write an espresso test in my application. In the application, I use dagger 2 and architecture components (LiveData, etc.). The test has a function to help me create fake injections for the tested activity. When I use it to mock the ManViewModel it works with no problem and I can run the test. But when I want to set a mock value for the ViewModelProvider.Factory the test throws an error in MainActivity: ViewModelProviders.of(th…iewModelImpl::class.java) must not be null

I have debugged the test and when I'm assigning the mock value it isn't null and in the main activity the values are not null but steel I get the error.

Some help would be appreciated.

The code for MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), AnimateFactsImage {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java) 
        // Here is the error: ViewModelProviders.of(th…iewModelImpl::class.java) must not be null
    }
}
```

The code for MainActiviyTest:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityView {
    @get:Rule
    val activityTestRule = object : ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java, true, false) {
        override fun beforeActivityLaunched() {
            super.beforeActivityLaunched()
            val myApp = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().applicationContext as MyApplication
            myApp.activityDispatchingAndroidInjector = createFakeActivityInjector<MainActivity> {
                mainViewModel = mainView
                viewModelFactory = mockMPF // TODO: fix problem, null pointer in activity
            }
        }
    }

    private val mockMPF = Mockito.mock(ViewModelProvider.Factory::class.java)

    private var mainView = Mockito.mock(MainViewModel::class.java)

    private val repoLiveData = MutableLiveData<ApiResponse<Result>>()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Mockito.`when`(mainView.getFactsList()).thenReturn(repoLiveData)
    }

    @Test
    fun isListDisplayed() {
        repoLiveData.postValue(ApiResponse(Result("title", arrayListOf(Row("title", "des", "img"))), null))
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(null)
        onView(withId(R.id.recycler_adapter)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a stacktrace?

Comment: Don't use a mock view model factory. Inject a stub instead that will return your mock view model.